# Is there a Kotlin std lib function to copy a list, removing all elements equal to ONE single element? A function taking only one non-collection arg?

Tags: kotlin

Given a list of arbitrary objects

```
input = listOf(a, b, c, a)
```

... is there a function (with one non-collection argument) in the Kotlin standard library that I can use to make a copy of this list, removing all instances of ONE object?

Something like:

```
val filtered = input.removeAllInstancesOf(a)
```

To clarify, I'm aware of other (potential) solutions to this task:

1. Using the filter function to do this. → `val output = input.filterNot { it == a }`
2. Using the minus function with a collection → `val output = input.minus(listOf(a))`
3. Using the minus function with a non-collection argument → `val output = input.minus(a)` ← Only removes the first instance of a!
4. Removing all instances from a mutable list.
5. Writing such a function. → Wrap any of the above.

... but I'm wondering why I can't find a function which takes just ONE, non-collection value.

Comment: IMO the first option is already clear enough (it's the first thing that came to my mind, anyway) that writing a function to encapsulate this behavior shouldn't be necessary. I don't believe there is a built-in that does this.

Answer (score 4):

> but I'm wondering why I can't find a function which takes just ONE, non-collection value.

Because that's a hyper-specific use-case of the already existing `filter` function. As you yourself showed it can be done in one line, and is probably the first thing a Kotlin dev would try to do (at least I would). So adding new function to the standard library probably doesn't add much value.

Comment: While I understand your argument, I'm not sure if it holds up... I don't think removing one item from a list is hyper specific. The mutable list has remove() .. and not just removeAll()  which one could use as a oneliner with a one-item list as well.

Comment: Well, mutableList is just an ArrayList under the hood, which already had a `remove(E item)` method, so I'd expect it's a holdover from that. Plus a List is a data structure that is defined by it's ability to add and remove items to / from arbitrary locations in constant time. Thus, having add / remove methods for specific items is expected. _Filtering_ by a specific condition is not.

Comment: The overall argument makes sense. The statement "Plus a List is a data structure that is defined by it's ability to add and remove items to / from arbitrary locations in constant time." is not really true though, a LinkedList doesn't allow random access at arbitrary locations, does it?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#get(int) - It seems like the Java implementation of `LinkedList` does, yes.

Comment: The presence of the get function doesn't mean that it's constant time. For a LinkedList, it would be linear, not constant.

Comment: Oh, sure, in that case it would not be constant time. I was thinking ArrayList with my initial comment. Sorry for the confusion with that, but "it's ability to add and remove items to / from arbitrary locations" is still a key aspect of a general List, hence the `add` and `remove` methods for both classes.